# unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) only on remote (not in local)

Tags: php, oop

We are developping a CRM.

In local, I have no problem, but in remote (OVH), I have this error message :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/dubinfo/www/CRM/model/Locataire.php on line 126

This is the code :

```
public function setVisites($visites) {
    $this->_visites = CheckTyper::isArrayOfModel($visites,
            VisiteMaisonInvestisseur::class, 'visites', __CLASS__);
}
```

The version of PHP on remote host (OVH) is 5.4.38

Comment: `class` is a reserved word. You shouldn't uses it as a property name.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using `class` as a name of a constant is available in PHP 5.5 only.

To get the class name you can replace `VisiteMaisonInvestisseur::class` with `get_class(new VisiteMaisonInvestisseur)`.

Or change the name of the constant. For example: `VisiteMaisonInvestisseur::class_name`.

Comment: thank you, I changed the php version on the production server, it works... Tnank you again

Comment: Couldn't change the php version on the server, so I used `get_class` instead. This error disappeared, but I got others, about `unexpected '('` or `unexpected (T_VARIABLE)` when I tried to put it inside a variable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `VisitMaisonInvestisseur::class`. `class` is a reserved word in PHP, so you can't use it as the name of a constant.

If it works on your local server, it must be version-specific. But I've tested this in 5.3 and 5.6, and they both report an error for `Classname::class`.

Comment: thank you, I changed the php version on the production server, it works... Tnank you again